# DatePickerDialog Romanian months

Tags: android, calendar

I have a script that shows up new DatePickerDialog(this, pickerListener, year, month,day);

Is there a way to change the month language? Or set it to a specific country.

Ex : i want that "Jan" (January) to be "Ian" ( Ianuarie in romanian language )

Any help will be good

Thanks.

Comment: Try making your own Custom Date Picker by using Spinner to populate it with custom month names

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use:

```
DateFormatSymbols.getInstance();
```